# Meta tags itemprop

Tags: html, meta-tags, microdata

I am trying to include extracted structured data in my webpages.

I included this for description:

```
<meta itemprop="description" content="my description" />
```

However I realised that there is already a normal meta description on the page:

```
<meta name="description" content="my description" />
```

Is it ok to leave both of them or it is really necessary to merge them together maybe like:

```
<meta itemprop="description" name="description" content="" />
```

Answer (score 28):

You *should* leave both of them. The [Microdata Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#content-models) says:

> If a meta element has an itemprop attribute, the name, http-equiv, and
>   charset attributes must be omitted, and the content attribute must be
>   present.

so it would be invalid to merge them.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but the quoted text clearly states that the `name`, `http-equiv` and `charset` attributes must be omitted, so leaving both the `itemprop` and `name` attribute is invalid.

Comment: @MichaëlvandeWeerd I parsed that statement similarly - I think the recommended practice then would be to have two meta tags, one with the itemprop and content, and another with name and content.

Comment: @WeNeigh - Correct.