# get_meta_tags() not working with meta tags that contain the "itemprop" attribute

Tags: php, html, meta-tags, microdata

simple problem.

I have a site that uses meta tags. I want to extract the meta tags with PHP. However, when using "itemprop" in addition to "name" `get_meta_tags()` doesn't work.

---

`<meta name="description" itemprop="description" content="Example content" />`

Output of `get_meta_tags()`

`false`

---

`<meta name="description" content="Example content" />`

Output of `get_meta_tags()`

`array (size=1)
  'description' => string 'Example content' (length=157)`

Do you have any idea why the itemprop addition makes such problems and if there's a method that can replace the `get_meta_tags()` or do I have to use sth. like phpQuery (since it's not recommended to use regex for html code)

Comment: [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14249518/3008050) According to this try removing the `name` attribute.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I already found it. The problem is, that get_meta_tags() doesn't care if there is ONLY `itemprop`. It has to be `meta`, and only meta for that method

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue at all; it returns `['description' => 'Example content']` for both scenarios.

Comment: Maybe has sth. to do with the php-version?

Answer (score 2):

It is [not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669) to have a `name` attribute and Microdata’s `itemprop` attribute on the same `meta` element.

So your HTML should look like:

```
<meta itemprop="description" content="Example content" />
<meta name="description" content="Example content" />
```

Comment: Hi, I know it's not valid html. When I said it's my page, it isn't really mine. I'm just checking if the site has some properties set and `get_meta_tags` didn't return the meta tags. Thanks though